# Socket available data for read

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I need fast method for check socket has available data for read.
I use select(), but it is not fast. 
Is faster method exists?

Comment: What is not 'fast' about it? How long it takes to call select(), thus the number of select's per second you can do. Or is the problem more how much total data processing you are doing. Define you meaning/expectation of 'fast'

Comment: I need check about 1000 sockets in 1/10 second, may be faster.

I tested select() with 1000 sockets. Each socket send 4 byte each 10 seconds. 1000 sockets were processed 1 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

select() tends to degrade for large sets of sockets due to the need to rebuild the fd_set, and the way it gives results.

The epoll() API on Linux is perhaps my favourite method of dealing with multiple sockets. You might take a quick look into it, but it is not available on Windows.

I believe the only way around select()'s limitations on Windows with that many sockets is to use IO-completion ports.

Comment: Rebuild the fd_set? You mean that the select() itself generates another fd_set with the ready to read sockets?

Comment: select() will modify any fd_set passed to it. Thus, on your next call, you must re-create a fd_set to pass to select() - either by going through your sockets, or by copying another fd_set, both of which are O(n) operations. APIs like epoll(), however, do not need to be passed a set of FDs - they remember them, and you notify the API of changes in your FD set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use completion ports on Windows. There are many online articles on how to use them.